# Change activity on server response

Tags: java, android, json

I'm trying to create a log-in activity and when I ask the server to check if the credentials are correct I should get a response, and use it to continue my task. The response arrive, but I'm unable to use it to continue.

```java
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password, final String token) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Caricamento ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response);
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DrawerActivity.class));
                    finish();
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    // Now store the user in SQLitesession.setLogin(session.setLogin(true);true);
                    String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

                    JSONObject user = jObj.getJSONObject("user");
                    String name = user.getString("name");
                    String email = user.getString("email");
                    String token = user.getString("cazzodigomma");
                    String created_at = user
                            .getString("created_at");

                    // Inserting row in users table
                    db.addUser(name, email, uid, created_at);

                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            DrawerActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Credenziali sbagliate, prego riprovare", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("Authorization", "Token token="+token);
            headers.put("Accept", "application/json");

            return headers;
        }

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);

            return params;
        }



       };

        //Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);

}
```

The JSON is

```
{"login":true}
```

Comment: can you show what actual response you getting ? is it only {"login":true} ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming that the JSON object is as as you would expect:**

It is because the line

```
jObj.getBoolean("error");
```

Is throwing an error which is taking you to the catch clause.

Try changing it to

```
jObj.optBoolean("error");
```

This is instead an optional boolean, if 'error' doesn't exist, it returns false instead of throwing an exception.

On a side note there are a few more issues you would encounter afterwards regarding the other 'get' methods but the same technique applies.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem in this way,
if the credentials are correct, send `{"login":true}`
if the credentials are not correct, send `{"login":false}`

then, replace the line `boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");`
with this line `boolean loginResponse= jObj.getBoolean("login");`
then `if (loginResponse) 
              {
                // enter the codes 
              }`